# Modify JQuery Progress Overlay Script

Tags: jquery

I have an overlay that is triggered when a submit button is pressed. Can anyone help me modify this script to work on pageload? Thankyou in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('div.submitbutton').click(function(event){
        $(this).val('Loading.. Please wait');
        $('#loading').show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#myform').submit();
        },200);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If jou make your loading div visible when the page is rendered. Than you just need to remove the loading div when everything is loaded:

```
<!-- This is valid in the <head> element in HTML5 -->
<noscript>
    <style>
        #loading { display: none; }
    </style>
</noscript>


<div id="loading">
    loading ...
</div>


$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#loading').hide();
});
```

Comment: This is how I usually handle the situation. If its a public facing site not all users may enable javascript, so this method will not work for those users. Keep that in mind.

Comment: that's true but I don't see a way of doing this when JavaScript is disabled :-( And actually I don't see much users who disable JavaScript except browsers for blind people.

Comment: You could use a <noscript> tag to add display: none; to the loading box (before the code for the loading box)